# Get the current temporary directory path in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript

The VB trick to get the path of the current temporary directory:

```
Private Declare Function GetTempPath Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetTempPathA" (ByVal nBufferLength As Long, ByVal lpBuffer As String) As Long
```

fails in VBScript. So?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetSpecialFolder(2)
```

It took me a while to find it on Google. So for the next one looking for the same as me...

Answer (score 38):

```
Const WindowsFolder = 0

Const SystemFolder = 1

Const TemporaryFolder = 2

Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim tempFolder: tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
```

Comment: Fabien's answer was correct as is this one, however, good documentation makes it easier for someone else to read.

Comment: this gets me `C:\windows`. Fabien's answer gets me the right folder `R:\Temp`

Answer (score 14):

Another possibility:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
```

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, I missed pasting a line, but that is better.

Comment: No problem. I was just about to paste my own, almost identical answer, when I saw you beat me by a second...again ;)

Comment: I like this one best because it's just as easy to use as `GetSpecialFolder`, but much less obscure. At least, for anyone who has ever worked with DOS or Windows environment variables AT ALL, this one is very intuitive and self-documenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can also keep using the `GetTempPath` API. It's a bit tricky to call APIs from vbscript though. Here are some pointers on how to make Win32 API calls from vbscript:

[Reference 1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48f022dd-f62d-437e-be0e-b502c8f4cd94/accessing-win32-api-in-vb-scriptvbs-files)

[Reference 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2f73269%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Reference 3](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/I3pjKPSyAR4)

Comment: You can describe more detail.

Comment: Actually, the links are not very useful and this should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based entirely on [AnthonyWJones' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/424349/7311767), here is my solution:

```
Public Enum SpecialFolder
    WindowsFolder = 0
    SystemFolder = 1
    TempFolder = 2
End Enum

Public Function GetFolder(folder As Integer) As String
    Dim objFSO  As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    GetFolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(folder)
End Function
```

So, for example, you'd use `GetFolder(TempFolder)` to obtain the pathname of the user's temp folder.