# Get SYSTEM temp folder?

Tags: vbscript, filesystems

I'm looking for something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424331/get-the-current-temporary-directory-path-in-vbscript).  However, I am looking specifically to dynamically find the location of the system's temp folder (i.e. the temp folder used by services.)

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching a little into this, I believe there is no way to use environment variables to capture the location of another user's %TEMP% folder (in this case the System user).

Answer (score 2):

Here you go (in VBS)

```
Set environmentVars = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process")
tempFolder = environmentVars("TEMP")
msgbox(tempFolder)
```

I'm not sure if your system will have an environment variable called "TEMP", so go to the command line and type

```
set
```

You'll get a list of environment vars, and their values. Pick the one that has your temp folder in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colEnvironment = objShell.Environment("PROCESS")
objPath = colEnvironment("temp")
WScript.Echo objPath
```

In that case

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set colEnvironment = objShell.Environment("PROCESS")
objPath = colEnvironment("windir")
WScript.Echo objPath & "\temp"
```

hope this will help

Comment: This still seems to be returning "my" temp dir. Rather than the system dir.  e.g. on WinXP I'm looking to get "C:\WINSOWS\Temp" and not my own temp dir.

Comment: Is "windir" consistent across other OS's?  Will services run on Server2008 still use %winddir%\Temp ?

Comment: You can also use "systemroot" instead of "windir". These all are Environment variables by default in the system and as far as I think, this should not change with new versions of windows, otherwise on upgrading the server all the previous installed applications (which uses these environment variables) will fail.

Comment: Whatever, let me mention it clearly here, that I don't know if temp folder for services resides at "%windir%\temp" or "%systemroot%\temp" for Server 2008 or not. I think anyone can having sever 2008 installed can help us by trying %systemroot%\temp in run window and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

The SYSTEM environment variables is stored in registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment

The environment variables for users is stored in registry keys: HKEY_USERS[user SID]\Environment

In order to get the value of any environment variable (in particular TEMP), need to check the presence of this variable in the branch for specified the user. If it is there, then you can use it. If it is not there, then you need to take a value from the system registry branch.

Answer (score -1):

In C#, its...

System.Collections.IDictionary Vars = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();

String TempPath = Vars["TEMP"];

You get an entire array of elements... Path, Temp, SessionName, PathExt, UserDomain, SystemDrive, WinDir, etc...

Comment: In C# I prefer using: Path.GetTempPath()

Comment: Yes, however, something like this will expose to others a larger group of elements they might not have otherwise known were there.  The System.Environment area has a lot of stuff available in it.

Comment: I think solution is required in vbscript.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this may be of some use: [System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx)