# Working with pictures in MS Access and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, image

How exactly does one go about:

1. getting images/pictures into a SQL database
2. viewing pictures from a SQL database using a MS Access form?

I currently use an ODBC link between the two databases with no problems at all, but I'm struggling to understand what I need to do to achieve what I'm trying to achieve.
I have already tried Google, but haven't yet come across the right information.

Answer (score 2):

### Getting pictures in and out of an SQL Server database:

You need the `GetChunk` and `AppendChunk` functions for that.
Here's a tutorial: [How To Read and Write BLOBs Using GetChunk and AppendChunk](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;194975&x=15&y=14).
This tutorial is a bit dated, but as far as I know this is still the best way to load/save pictures in a database from VBA.
Note that in SQL Server, you should use a `varbinary(max)` field (instead of the `image` suggested in the tutorial) to store the pictures.

### Displaying the pictures in an MS Access form:

You can't display a picture directly from the database. You have to load it from the database *(see above)*, store it in a temp folder and display it from there.

To get Windows' temp folder, use `Environ("temp")` or [the `GetTempPath` API function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/424331/6884).

To display the picture you can either set it as the background of the form:

```
Me.Picture = "c:\...\temp\picture.jpg"
```

...or use a image control:

```
Me.NameOfImageControl.Picture = "c:\...\temp\picture.jpg"
```